# How to predict the household water consumption in 2050

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I have data related to the household water consumption.

The key issue is whether we need more water purification plant in the future or not.

The population will be decreasing. It means that household water consumption will be going down.

However, the number of one- and two-person household will be going up. it means that household water consumption will be going up.
Because LPCD(Liter Per Capita Day) of one- or two-person household is larger than over three-person household based on the household water consumption.

Therefore, I want to know whether we need more water purification plant in 2050 or not.

I added the dataset and my code.
The result of my code was not good.

Could you check my code and algorithm?

the data is below.

I would like to explain the data shortly.

It has 8 columns. The dependent variable is only one which is the household_water_consumption_unit_ton.
The year column is the index.
I would like to predict the household_water_consumption_unit_ton in 2050.
Finally, I would like to add a new column whose name is the predicted household_water_consumption_unit_ton
next to the household_water_consumption_unit_ton.

```
year population one_person_household two_person_household three_person_household four_person_household over_five_person_household household_water_consumption_unit_ton
2000 9987930 504192 524864 672410 992600 398643 736533992
2001 10000519 547177 552125 680530 974176 377162 737784659
2002 9958941 587392 578067 691449 965620 360548 720900652
2003 9951247 627630 604403 702167 955230 343748 728580066
2004 9961348 664390 628852 712084 944864 327397 736276327
2005 9938574 680954 667925 734488 925190 314516 731047705
2006 9967058 715994 687962 747218 908864 305547 730195428
2007 9978147 752891 710167 758626 888833 296230 723904433
2008 10021075 789796 732572 770074 868434 286999 720192072
2009 10047820 827183 754501 781133 848992 278113 720065222
2010 9998015 873490 780516 793852 819605 273818 721759866
2011 9981786 912149 806492 810168 805059 267042 717440010
2012 9946147 942756 826655 816961 780740 256541 718772932
2013 9900300 974726 849422 827169 759895 247346 716525298
2014 9885586 1009040 872664 838736 742139 238961 709886455
2015 9851890 1091753 913206 809929 704925 221480 713414487
2016 9754115 1120942 922630 809776 685456 211842 713140965
2017 9678697 1156019 939794 807432 664832 201401 706671587
2018 9610366 1202059 961845 802325 640190 190013 707667562
2019 9570573 1264616 986824 796531 616312 178206 702018748
2020 9531427 1347931 1015012 788615 601117 165243 726236303
2021 9416204 1442762 1040803 776135 578948 152862 723061075
2022 9326928 1470829 1060934 772956 558695 146904 697989260
2023 9254416 1495933 1083138 770345 538590 141003
2024 9188176 1518992 1104487 768119 519801 135338
2025 9127282 1539412 1126594 765091 500890 129830
2026 9069928 1555388 1147789 762289 483018 124543
2027 9015625 1568297 1165635 760139 467095 119791
2028 8963931 1579372 1183329 757447 451001 115112
2029 8914421 1587827 1199847 754807 435503 110598
2030 8867287 1594075 1215913 751805 420406 106351
2031 8822602 1598285 1231512 749002 406041 102357
2032 8780403 1603390 1243871 745645 392901 98754
2033 8740499 1607832 1255842 741746 380126 95369
2034 8702725 1611749 1267765 737249 367466 92070
2035 8666810 1615786 1278195 732706 355650 89005
2036 8630627 1617794 1288960 728200 344472 86150
2037 8592309 1621666 1298302 721994 333335 83217
2038 8551772 1624230 1307370 715364 322635 80473
2039 8508790 1625820 1315638 708488 312078 77784
2040 8463136 1626839 1322376 701038 301812 75173
2041 8414718 1624355 1329443 693890 291957 72606
2042 8363292 1620407 1335766 686966 281866 69790
2043 8308708 1614025 1340496 680521 272400 67142
2044 8250943 1605772 1344088 673708 263321 64596
2045 8190084 1597183 1345850 666053 254362 62098
2046 8126485 1585580 1347217 659039 245656 59640
2047 8060229 1572726 1347318 652280 237100 57257
2048 7991561 1560062 1344803 645322 229015 55049
2049 7920659 1547577 1340961 637729 220988 52794
2050 7847750 1536003 1335075 630048 213087 50547
```

my code
The code was written in colab.
The result of my code was not good.

```
!python -m pip install tensorflow scikit_learn pandas
import pandas
df = pandas.read_excel('dataset.xlsx', index_col = 0)
df

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_df, test_df = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.1, random_state=5) # train data : test data = 9:1
train_df, valid_df = train_test_split(train_df, test_size=0.2, random_state=5)# train data : valid data = 8 :2

split independent variable and dependent variable
X_train, y_train = train_df.iloc[:, :-1], train_df.iloc[:,-1]
X_valid, y_valid = valid_df.iloc[:, :-1], valid_df.iloc[:,-1]
X_test, y_test = test_df.iloc[:, :-1], test_df.iloc[:,-1]

print(X_train.shape, y_train.shape)
print(X_valid.shape, y_valid.shape)
print(X_test.shape, y_test.shape)

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import InputLayer, Dense

model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape = (6,))) # independent variables 6
model.add(Dense(1))

from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
model.compile(loss=MeanSquaredError())

model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data = (X_valid, y_valid), epochs = 1000, verbose = 0)
```

Comment: The population and total water consumption are both very obviously trending down.  You don't need any more water plants.

Answer (score 0):

If you plot a line graph with the year as your x axis, you can make a line for columns 2-8 (with the line for column 8 cutting off early). That will make it a lot easier to see how all the trends increase and decrease, and how they compare and correlate to each other. For the household_water_consumption_unit_ton specifically, you can take a look at the line so far to get a guess at how the trend might continue. [Here's](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.line.html) the documentation for making line plots.

Depending on how deep you want to go into it, you can use [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) to get an estimate on how the trend will continue, or you can just eyeball it to get a basic idea of how the trends seem to be going (eg: increasing at an increasing rate, increasing at a decreasing rate, decreasing at a consistent rate, etc.). It'd also keep the other columns in mind too, since if the perceived trend one of the other columns is following changes drastically between 2023 and 2050, that may or may not mean the trend for column 8 might change in drastically as well.